# php page won't recognize a function included in another file

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a variable to a function that selects a table from a database. It has worked all the other times I have been using the function, but now I get this error message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: post in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\single.php on line 50

Now when I try to use another function that I have and set the same variable it doesn't work either. For some reason on this single.php page it will not recognize the function that I have in another file. The file where functions are lies included in posts.php, in a file called db.php, like this:

single.php :

```
<?php include('path.php');?>
<?php include('posts.php'); 



if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
  
 $post = selectOne('posts', ['id' => $_GET['id']]);
  
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <title><?php echo $post['title'];?> </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <!--  <script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src =
      'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2&appId=285071545181837&autoLogAppEvents=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script> -->
  <!-- header -->
  <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/includes/header.php"); ?>
  <!-- // header -->
  <!-- Page wrapper -->
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="content clearfix">
      <div class="page-content single">
        <h2 style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h2>
        <br>
      <?php echo html_entity_decode($post['body']); ?>

       
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar single">
        <!-- fb page -->
        
        <!-- // fb page -->
        <!-- Popular Posts -->
        <div class="section popular">
          <h2>Popular</h2>
          <div class="post clearfix">
            <img src="images/image_1.png">
            <a href="#" class="title">How to act inspite of your emotions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post clearfix">
            <img src="images/image_2.png">
            <a href="#" class="title">How to act inspite of your emotions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post clearfix">
            <img src="images/image_3.png">
            <a href="#" class="title">How to act inspite of your emotions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post clearfix">
            <img src="images/image_4.png">
            <a href="#" class="title">How to act inspite of your emotions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post clearfix">
            <img src="images/image_5.png">
            <a href="#" class="title">How to act inspite of your emotions</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- // Popular Posts -->
        <!-- topics -->
        <div class="section topics">
          <h2>Topics</h2>
          <ul>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Poems</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Quotes</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Fiction</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Biography</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Motivation</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Inspiration</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Life Lessons</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Self Development</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- // topics -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- // content -->
  </div>
  <!-- // page wrapper -->
  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/includes/footer.php"); ?>
  <!-- // FOOTER -->
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Slick JS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

posts.php:

```
<?php

include("app/database/db.php");
include("app/helpers/validatePost.php"); 

$table = 'posts'; 

$topics = selectAll('topics');
$posts = selectAll($table);


$errors = array();
$title = "";
$id = "";
$body = "";
$topic_id = "";
$published ="";

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $_GET['id']]);
    
    $id = $post['id'];
    $title = $post['title'];
    $body = $post['body'];
    $topic_id = $post['topic_id'];
    $published = $post['published'];
}

if (isset($_GET['delete_id'])){
    $count = delete($table, $_GET['delete_id']);
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Post deleted succefully";
        $_SESSION['type'] = "success";
        header("location: " . BASE_URL . "/admin/posts/index.php");
        exit();
}

if(isset($_GET['published']) && isset($_GET['p_id'])){
    $published = $_GET['published'];
    $p_id = $_GET['p_id'];
    $count = update($table, $p_id, ['published' => $published]);
   $_SESSION['message'] = "Post published state changed";
    $_SESSION['type'] = "success";
    header("location: " . BASE_URL . "/admin/posts/index.php");
    exit();
    
}



if (isset($_POST['add-post'])){
   $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
        $image_name = time() . ' _ ' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = ROOT_PATH . "/assets/images/" . $image_name;

     $result =   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
    if ($result) {
        $_POST ['image'] = $image_name;

    } else{
        array_push($errors, 'failed to upload image');
    }

    } else{
        array_push($errors, "Post image required");
    }


    if(count($errors) == 0) {
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $_POST['user_id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
        $_POST['published'] = isset($_POST['published']) ? 1 : 0;
        $_POST['body'] = htmlentities($_POST['body']);

        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Post created succefully";
        $_SESSION['type'] = "success";
        header("location: " . BASE_URL . "/admin/posts/index.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic_id = $_POST['topic_id'];
        $published = isset($_POST['published']) ? 1 : 0;
    }

}

if(isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);

    if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
        $image_name = time() . ' _ ' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = ROOT_PATH . "/assets/images/" . $image_name;

        $result =   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
    if ($result) {
        $_POST ['image'] = $image_name;

    } else{
        array_push($errors, 'failed to upload image');
    }

    } else{
        array_push($errors, "Post image required");
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $_POST['user_id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
        $_POST['published'] = isset($_POST['published']) ? 1 : 0;
        $_POST['body'] = htmlentities($_POST['body']);

        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Post updated succefully";
        $_SESSION['type'] = "success";
        header("location: " . BASE_URL . "/admin/posts/index.php");
        
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic_id = $_POST['topic_id'];
        $published = isset($_POST['published']) ? 1 : 0;
    }

}
```

db.php: (There are more functions, but i only included the two I tried to use with the variable $post.

```
 function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
   
            //return srecords that match conditions
            $i = 0;
            foreach($conditions as $key => $value) {
               if ($i === 0){

               
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
             } else{
                 $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?";
             }
              $i++;
            }

            $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
            $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            return $records;
        
   }

function dd($value){
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: You are defining a variable `$post` Inside an IF statement. So if `$_GET['id']` is not set, then the variable `$post` is never created.

Comment: If you pass an `id` the code will work, if for some reason you dont, it will give this error

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made a silly typo, ?=id instead of ?id= So much frustration for such a little thing